# Depth of water in a leaking tank

Tags: trigonometry

The depth of water in a leaking storage tank is $d$ cm at time $t$ hours after midnight on Sunday. The value of $d$ is given by

$$d = 10 - 2 \sqrt{3}\cos4t^0 - 2\sin4t^0$$

Find

- The least and greatest depth of water possible with this model.
- The time at which the depth first reaches these values.

Although I’d really appreciate the answers, I would be more than content if someone could advise me on what needs to be done to solve the question above. Apologies for any unclear areas. Thank you to anyone who takes the time to answer or even look at this question.

Comment: Hint: transform $d$ to $10+a\sin(4(t-t_0))$ it is then easier to study the derivative.

Comment: What is the meaning of the $0$ in the exponent?

Comment: @CarefreeXplorer I'd assume that is at time $t=0$

Comment: @HungaryGoose Wouldn't $d$ be a constant then and not a function of $t$?

Answer (score 0):

### Hints

1. Let $x = 4t$.
2. Attempt converting $-2\sqrt{3}\cos(x) - 2\sin(x)$ in the form $R\cos(\alpha + x)$.
3. Recall that $\cos(\alpha + \beta) = \cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta) - \sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$.
4. Recall that $-1 \le \cos(x) \le 1$.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply. Your advice clarified many of the areas I was uncertain of. Thanks again